# SYSDATE in ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to get the system date using the `SYSDATE` function in oracle, but I keep getting results equal to the number of rows in the table I'm requesting the system date from

Here how my code looks like:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)As Currnt_Time FROM TABLE_NAME
```

And this is my output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMjOc.png)

The result is displaying the current time N times, I just want it to display it one time

Comment: If you query a table of _n_ rows without supplying a `where`, `distinct`, `group by` or any other clause that might reduce the result set, obviously you will get _n_ results back, i.e. a result for each row in the table. I'm not sure why you would expect anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest command should be:

SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)As Currnt_Time FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ROWNUM = 1

And this is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: you have to have a FROM CLAUSE - sybase and sql server support this, but Oracle does not

Comment: the poster wants today's date, not the user name. Also, DUAL only has 1 row, so adding a rownum = 1 is superfluous.

Comment: Try this: SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

Comment: What is the context in which you want SYSDATE? While selecting from DUAL is "correct", there may be an easier, better, more efficient way depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: True. I usually turn my head to the left and look at the calendar on the wall; *today* is red marked. That's quite inexpensive way of selecting TRUNC(SYSDATE).

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)As Currnt_Time FROM dual;
```

DUAL only has 1 column, one row. So you'll get one answer.

You're asking to run a select on a table, so it will apply across all rows, unless you provide a predicate.

So you COULD do this, but don't.

```
select trunc(SYSDATE)as CURRNT_TIME from TABLE
where rownum < 2;
```

This will always be more expensive than using the [DUAL table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Selecting-from-the-DUAL-Table.html#GUID-0AB153FC-5238-4E79-8522-C9E2A04AB5E4). That's why we built it, in fact.

Comment: Actually, dual was originally created to create 2 rows from 1 by joining to it (it had 2 dummy rows originally, hence the name "dual").  But its obviously changed since ;-)

Comment: Just a little concerned that you are calling your result "CURRENT_TIME".  Be aware that using TRUNC will *remove* the time portion, ie, the result will be midnight on the current day.  If you want current *time*, then do not include the TRUNC

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald I think your comment applies to the original question, not jeff's answer :)

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald yeah the whole time/date thing...such a fun lesson to get into

Comment: Yes @JeffreyKemp  - was for the original poster